# Reload template variable without refreshing in django

Tags: python, django, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I will auto update **template variable** without refresh web page when spark streaming finished in **view.py**

**view.py**

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Python Spark SQL basic example").config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value").getOrCreate()
schema = StructType().add("_c0", "integer").add("InvoiceNo", "string").add("Quantity","integer").add("InvoiceDate","date").add("UnitPrice","integer").add("CustomerID","double").add("TotalSales","integer")
INPUT_DIRECTORY = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../jsonFileInput")
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../jsonFileOutput")
CHECKPOINT_DIRECTORY = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../writestream_checkpoints")
dataStream = spark.readStream.format("json").schema(schema).load(INPUT_DIRECTORY)

query = dataStream \
    .writeStream \
    .format("json") \
    .option("checkpointLocation",CHECKPOINT_DIRECTORY) \
    .option("path", OUTPUT_DIRECTORY) \
    .start()

def dashboardV2 (request):
    df = spark.read.format('json').schema(schema).option('header',True).load(OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)
    totalSales = codeData.totalSales(df)
    ncustomer = codeData.allCustomer(df)
    return render(request,'dashboardV2.html',{
        'totalSales': totalSales,
        'ncustomer': ncustomer
    })
```

I need to auto update *totalSales* and *ncustomer* variable in template when streaming data. (df variable will read json file that spark streaming and use it to calculate in function for *totalSales* and *ncustomer* variable)

**template.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <label class="valueTotalSales2017">$ {{totalSales}} M</label>
        <label class="valueNumCus2017">{{ncustomer}}</label>
    </body>
</html>
```

**codeData.py**

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Python Spark SQL basic example").config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value").getOrCreate()

def totalSales(df):
    total = df.select('TotalSales').groupby().sum().toPandas()
    total = total['sum(TotalSales)'][0]/1000000 # convert to millions
    total = "%.2f" % total   # trim 2 decimal
    return total

def allCustomer(df):
    ncus = df.select('CustomerID').distinct().count()
    return ncus
```

Thank for your helping.

Comment: do you need some kind of ajax?

Comment: In order to get data from the backend server (django) without refreshing the page, you need to use AJAX in your javascript code, which retrieves data asynchronously from the server.

Comment: Oh!! thanks. I'm a beginner coding. I will try learn it. Can you give me an example ajax coding?

Comment: you need to make some sort of view that returns:JsonResponse(response, content_type='application/json')